# C free an array multidimensional correctly

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, valgrind, free

I have this following code, and i really don't understand why i have this **segmentation fault**

```
static char** game_alloc(char **game, int n, int m) {
    game = calloc(n, sizeof(char *));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        game[i]= calloc(m, sizeof(char));
    }
    if(*game == NULL) {
        perror("Error: calloc in not initialized correctly");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return game;
}

static void game_free(char **game, int n) {

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
        free(game[0]);
    }
    free(game);
}
```

The problem is when i call the function `game_free`. I have a segementation fault with the `free`

When i run it into `valgrind` i have this :

```
==11449== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==11449==    at 0x400AE5: game_free (john.c:27)
==11449==    by 0x400DAE: main (john.c:114)
==11449== 
==11449== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==11449==    at 0x4C29730: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:468)
==11449==    by 0x400AEF: game_free (john.c:27)
==11449==    by 0x400DAE: main (john.c:114)
==11449==  Address 0x495641ff89415741 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==11449== 
==11449== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==11449==    at 0x4C296E6: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:468)
==11449==    by 0x400B07: game_free (john.c:29)
==11449==    by 0x400DAE: main (john.c:114)
==11449== 
==11449== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==11449==    at 0x4C29730: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:468)
==11449==    by 0x400B07: game_free (john.c:29)
==11449==    by 0x400DAE: main (john.c:114)
==11449==  Address 0x400f10 is in the Text segment of /autofs/netapp/account/cremi/mpuygren/MasterCSI/projet/john-2/john
==11449== 
==11449== 
==11449== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11449==     in use at exit: 33 bytes in 4 blocks
==11449==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 33 bytes allocated
```

Don't understand, i follow this post but ....

[C: Correctly freeing memory of a multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733881/c-correctly-freeing-memory-of-a-multi-dimensional-array)

Comment: Just to spread the word, this is **not** a multidimensional array. It is only an emulation of it. C has real multidimensional arrays with variable bounds since 1999. Among other things you would avoid this particular problem by using the correct tool from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
        free(board[0]);
    }
```

write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
        free(board[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be `free(game[i]);`, instead of `free(game[0]);`