# Memory management in allocating 2-D array

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have allocated a two dimensional array using the following code:

```
// Dynamic allocation
        int **matrix=new int*[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            matrix[i]=new int[n];
        }
```

This works fine.

- Firstly we allocate an array of integer pointers.
- Then we further allocate each of the earlier pointer to point at a memory location of `n` integers. This creates our two dimensional array.

I know that a destructor for a dynamically allocated array should look like:

```
~SquareMatrix()
{
delete [] OneDarray;
}
```

The emphasis being on `[]` because if it is not written, only the first element of the array will be deleted.

On similar grounds, I guess I need to place the `[]` twice so as to delete the entire two dimensional array, like,

`delete [] [] matrix;`

But this is not working and giving a compile time error.

**What is the correct way of doing it?**

Comment: Destroy things exactly the *opposite* of how you allocated them. Just invoking `delete [] matrix` is not doing that. you used a loop for your construction, you need one for your destruction as well. (and ideally, don't do *any* of this in the first place: use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` and let the standard lib work for you. Stop playing in the C++ sandbox with a C pail-and-shovel).

Comment: possible duplicate of [C: Correctly freeing memory of a multi-dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733881/c-correctly-freeing-memory-of-a-multi-dimensional-array)

Comment: @WhozCraig, Thank you. That is a point I will try not to forget ever. Do things exactly opposite of what I did in allocation. And yes, the school assignment requires it to be strictly an array and not a vector. :)

Comment: @AkshayArora too bad for that; best of luck. (and get ready to fulfill [The Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) for that object class; you're going to need it).

Comment: @WhozCraig, Wish I could "+1" your "answer". Comments give no reputation. Unfair.

Comment: Both answers below are more than adequate. No worries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    delete [] matrix[i];
}

delete [] matrix
```

You need to delete each of the internal arrays and then delete the array.

As has been suggested in a comment.  A safer way of doing this would be to use standard containers such as `std::vector`.  You could do something like this then:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;
```

This would give you a two dimensional array but you would not have to handle the cleanup.

Comment: [**give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime)

Answer (score 3):

> *"**What is the correct way of doing it?**"*

Using standard containers like e.g. `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` or `std::array<std::array<int,N>,N>` (supposed `N` is already known at compile time) is the *correct* way.
You don't use `new()`/`new[]` and `delete`/`delete[]` in 1st place (besides rare valid use cases).

If you're sure you have such case, you delete in exactly the reverse order as you were allocating using `new[]`. `delete [][];` isn't valid syntax, as the compiler already told you.