# Program crashes while freeing dynamically allocated memory

Tags: c++

I'm representing a graph using an adjacency list here.

Here is the code:

```
// A program to check the reachability between two nodes within a specified number of steps using an adjacency list
/***************************************************************************/

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    int value;
    node* next;

    // Constructors:
    node() {
        value = 0;
        next = 0;
    }
    node(int x) {
        value = x;
        next = 0;
    }
};


node* al; // Adjacency list
int n; // Number of nodes
int node1, node2, k; // For reading input from the console
int counter;

bool checkReachability(int, int, int);
void freeMemory();

int main() {

    ifstream in;
    in.open("Input.txt");
    if(in) {
        in >> n;
        al = new node[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            al[i].value = i+1;
        }

        int a, b;
        while(in >> a >> b) {
            node* temp = &al[a-1];
            while(temp->next != 0) {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            temp->next = new node(b);    
        }

        cout << "\n\nThe adjacency list representation of the graph is as follows: \n";
        cout << "________________________________\n\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cout << al[i].value;
            node* temp = al[i].next;
            while(temp != 0) {
                cout << "->" << temp->value;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "________________________________\n";
        in.close();
        char c;
        do {
            cout << "\nPlease enter the input (node1, node2, k): \n";
            cin >> node1 >> node2 >> k;
            counter = 0;
            if (checkReachability(node1 - 1, node2, k)) {
                cout << "\nReachable within " << k << " steps";
                if (counter < k) {
                    cout << " (actually " << counter << ")";
                }
                cout << endl << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "\nNot reachable within " << k << " steps  \n";
            }
            cout << "\nDo you want to continue? Y/N \n\n";
            cin >> c;
        } while (c == 'Y' || c == 'y');
        freeMemory();
    } else {
        cout << "\nCouldn't find the input file\n\n";
    }
    return 0;
}

bool checkReachability(int n1, int n2, int k) {
    if ((n1 + 1) == n2) return true;
    counter++;
    if (counter <= k) {
        node* temp = &(al[n1]);
        while (temp != 0) {
            if (temp->value == n2) return true;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp = al[n1].next; 
        while (temp != 0) {
            if (checkReachability(((temp->value)-1),n2,k)) return true;
            counter--;
            temp = temp->next;
        }   
    }
    return false;
}

void freeMemory() {
    cout << "\nFreeing memory...\n";
    // To free the dynamically allocated memory on the heap
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        node* temp = &al[i];
        while(temp != 0) {
            node* temp2 = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
            delete temp2;
        }
    }
    //delete [] al;
    cout << "\nMemory freed.\n";
}
```

The program runs just fine. It's only when I choose to exit it, which calls the freeMemory function that it crashes. Please help me figure out what the problem is.

Input.txt file:

```
5
1 2
2 5
3 4
1 3
```

Output:

```
The adjacency list represent
____________________________

1->2->3
2->5
3->4
4
5
____________________________

Please enter the input (node
1 2 1

Reachable within 1 steps


Do you want to continue? Y/N

y

Please enter the input (node
2 4 4

Not reachable within 4 steps

Do you want to continue? Y/N

N

Freeing memory...
```

And then, it crashes.

Comment: Double `delete` I'd suspect. See here also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28649952/memory-management-in-allocating-2-d-array/28649991#28649991

Comment: May as well paste up the input file content as well, preferably something reasonable that reproduces your issue. Added to the question please. The output run up-to-and-including the crash wouldn't be unwelcome either.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Ok, just added the Input.txt file.

Comment: I suspect your cleanup loop is `delete` ing the initial entry in your array, which was *not* dynamically allocated. Only the entries *chained* via `next` are allocated stand-alone with `new`. The initial holdings of `a[]` are a vector allocation. I'd check there.

Comment: Added the output too.

Comment: I think the first element is also dynamically allocated, when I typed:  `al = new node[n];`

Comment: @SoutheeRocks it is vector-allocated. Each node `a[i]` is *not* individually allocated. Only the corresponding adjacency chains hun on them afterward are. See posted answer below.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`). Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) if available.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
void freeMemory() {
    cout << "\nFreeing memory...\n";
    // To free the dynamically allocated memory on the heap
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        node* temp = &al[i]; // HERE
        while(temp != 0) {
            node* temp2 = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
            delete temp2;
        }
    }
    delete [] al;
    cout << "\nMemory freed.\n";
}
```

The initial vector `a1` is allocated via `new node[n]`. Meaning the initial entries in all slots `a1[0...n-1]` are part of the vector allocation; not part of the *chained* adjacency sequences associated to each node thereafter. I believe you need to do this:

```
void freeMemory() {
    cout << "\nFreeing memory...\n";
    // To free the dynamically allocated memory on the heap
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        node* temp = al[i].next; // start with next pointer
        while(temp != 0) {
            node* temp2 = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
            delete temp2;
        }
    }
    delete [] al;
    cout << "\nMemory freed.\n";
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a *pointer* array from inception and dynamically single-allocate *all* nodes, not just the adjacency chains, at which time your loop for freeing would work, but the rest of your code would need some alteration. Given how far you are along with this, I'd just make the change I show above and call it good.

Comment: Thanks a ton buddy, really appreciate. So, the problem is that each al[i] is getting deleted twice, right? But, I tried commenting out the second last line, i.e `delete [] al` but still get the same error. :(

Comment: I think all the nodes are allocated dynamically mate. I mean, obviously, the adjacency chains are dynamically allocated, but whenever I add a new node to the chain, I did:  `temp->next = new node(b); `. So, that was dynamic, too right?

Comment: @SoutheeRocks again, not all of them they're not. The initial set of nodes composing what becomes `a1[]` are vector-allocated via `new node[]` as I said, you could forego that scheme and simply use a `node*` pointer array `new node*[n]` from the get-go. After all, those first nodes have nothing more than `i+1` for their "values" anyway; not like you couldn't do the math on that. It would take significant code changes. Regardless, trust me. The initial vector of `n` nodes stored in `a1[]` are singularly dynamic like all the adjacency adds afterward.