# Free() from 2 dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to free mem from 2 dimensional array the same way like in this: [[C: Correctly freeing memory of a multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733881/c-correctly-freeing-memory-of-a-multi-dimensional-array/1733945#1733945])

```
//initialization
int **tab;
int i,j;
int x_max=5,y_max=7;
tab = calloc(x_max+1, sizeof(int));
for(j = 0; j <=x_max+1; j++)
{
    tab[j] = calloc(y_max+2, sizeof(int));
}
```

and than:

```
for (i = 0; i <=x_max+1; i++)
{
    free(tab[i]);
}
free(tab);
```

This seems to be like in the example in above link, but my program keeps crashing (when I comment freeing mem part everything works good.) Also when I try to debug program line by line everything works. (Debugger finished with status 0)

Comment: You have undefined behavior while *creating* said array (repeated when you're freeing it, but by that point, it does not matter anymore because of earlier UB). You allocate `x_max+1` elements, and yet you access `x_max+2` (`0` to `x_max+1` inclusive). In most cases, you do *not* want a `<=` in a `for` loop in C.

Comment: `tab = calloc(x_max+1, sizeof(int));
for(j = 0; j <=x_max+1; j++)` --> `tab = calloc(x_max+1, sizeof(int*));
for(j = 0; j <x_max+1; j++)`

Comment: @cokceken Huh? That's not valid C. Array indexing requires an index between the `[` and `]`.

Comment: @tuple_cat you are right i deleted my comment

Comment: There is no 2D array in your code. Something like `int **` is not and cannot point to a 2D array. Use a 2D array.

Comment: The <= should be replaced by <. As a general rule, always write for loops with <, never with <=.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's not a 2D array. It's a *jagged* array.

Your initial allocation is problematic. You want to allocate `x_max+1` pointers, not `int`s. And you are accessing outside of the bounds since you allocated `x_max+1` pointers, yet access upto `x_max+2` pointers.

It's usually preferred to use the thing itself to allocate memory such as:

```
tab = calloc(x_max+1, sizeof *tab);
```

so that you don't need to worry about the type being changed later.

```
tab = calloc(x_max+1, sizeof(int));
for(j = 0; j <=x_max+1; j++)
{
    tab[j] = calloc(y_max+2, sizeof(int));
}
```

should be

```
tab = calloc(x_max+1, sizeof *tab); /* equivalent to: tab = calloc(x_max+1, sizeof(int*)); */
for(j = 0; j < x_max+1; j++)
{
    tab[j] = calloc(y_max+2, sizeof(int));
}
```

You should also check the return value of `calloc()` for failures.

Comment: Code could use  `tab = calloc(x_max+1, sizeof *tab);` and `tab[j] = calloc(y_max+2, sizeof *(tab[j]));`, for simpler code.  Less likely to code wrong, easier to review and update.

Comment: How can I check if it's NULL or not? is this ok? `if (tab==NULL)`

Comment: @sswwqqaa Yes, that's fine. Similarly, check for the allocations done inside the loop too.