# How I change string of strings at C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, function, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have string of strings that I want send to a function and change the strings of the string.

How do I send the string to the function ? With 2 `*` or with 3 `*`? For example:

I want change and add the `str[0]` and `str[1]`. How do I send it to the function?
Also, how do I send it to `freeStr`? Is it the the same as sending it to the change function?

```
int main(void)
{
    char **str = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3);
    str[0] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    str[1] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);

    changeStr(str);
    freeStr(str);
}

void changeStr(/* ... */)
{
}
```

Comment: The computer will not blow up if you try different alternatives. And if you compile with `-Wall -Wextra` the compiler will most likely warn you if you do anything wrong.

Comment: `free` what you `malloc` (or `calloc` or even maybe `realloc`) .... you have `str[0] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);` so you need `free(str[0])` ... you have `char** str=(char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*3);` so you need `free(str);`

Comment: The cast to the return value of `malloc()` is, at best, redundant, and it may hide an error the compiler would have caught otherwise.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733881/c-correctly-freeing-memory-of-a-multi-dimensional-array

Comment: Unrelated: prefer `int main(void) { ... }` for your main function

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Also, make sure to also pass the length (in both dimensions) of the array to your function, otherwise you will have no way to safely access it.

Answer (score -1):

> How do I send the string to the function? With 2 `*` or with 3 `*`?

First, The parameter at the definition/declaration of `changePtr` has to be with two `*` (`char **`) or respectively with one `*` and you address the amount of elements at an array declarator which gains also a pointer to pointer to `char` (`char *p[] == char **p`).

```
// Definition of changeStr.
void changeStr (char** p)
{
      // some stuff going on here.
}
```

OR

```
// Definition of changeStr.
void changeStr (char* p[])
{
      // some stuff going on here.
}
```

OR

```
// Definition of changeStr.
void changeStr (size_t elem, char* p[elem])
{
      // some stuff going on here.
}
```

Triple pointers are considered as bad practice and one of them is not really needed here. It would make things even more complicated.

---

You call the function like this

```
changeStr(str);
```

for 1st and 2nd case, and

```
changeStr(sizeof(str) / sizeof(*str), str);
```

for the third case.

For the last case, The first argument evaluates the amount of elements, the second passes the value of the pointer to pointer to `char` `str` by value to `changeStr`.

---

> Also, how I send it to `freeStr`? The same as I send to the change function?

Yes, but inside of the function you need to deallocate the allocated space for each separate string first. After that you can `free()` the array of pointer to `char` `str`. If you `free()` the array of pointer to `char` first you ain't got the possibility to free the memory of the strings anymore and thus you have a memory leak.